# Is there a way to check a setting and run tests only if that setting is set?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to check a setting and run tests only if that setting is True?
Is it possible to do this in the setup method so that no test cases are run if a flag is set to false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this is using [skipIf and skipUnless](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.skip). You can use them to skip entire test cases or specific tests.

```python
from unittest import skipIf

from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase


@skipIf(settings.MY_SETTING == 'whatever', 'ensure setting is set')
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    # ...
    pass


class MyTestCase2(TestCase):

    @skipIf(settings.MY_SETTING == 'whatever', 'ensure setting is set')
    def test_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```

Comment: Nice, that is new for me, tx!

Answer (score 2):

You can creat your own `test` [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/), by extending django's `test` command.

Over there you an check for settings and run test preferentially.

```
from django.core.management import CommandError
from django.core.management.commands.test import Command as TestCommand


class Command(TestCommand):

    def __init__(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        try:
            if not settings.TEST_SETTING:
                raise CommandError('Command error')
        except:
            raise CommandError('Command Error')
        super(Command, self).__init__()
```